Django ORM Query aggregate datetime + timeoffset and filter on new value
I've the following table structure (note localised start time):



id
start_time
offset
score




1
2024-06-14 02:03:00.000 +0200
+1000
15


2
2024-06-14 02:04:00.000 +0200
+1000
15


3
2024-06-14 02:05:00.000 +0200
+1000
12


4
2024-06-14 02:06:00.000 +0200
+1000
10



I'm trying to come up with a query that fetch all the entries, where start time localised at column offset is greater than a given date.
So far i tried something on the line of:
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')

localized_start_time = ExpressionWrapper(
    TruncDate('start_time', tzinfo=utc) + F('offset'), output_field=models.DateTimeField()
)

result = MyModel.objects.annotate(
    localized_start_time=localized_start_time
).filter(
    localized_start_time=datetime.now()
)

however when running the output query, i'm getting:
operator does not exist: date + character varying
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Any clue on how to add localised start time using the value on column offset?
Unfortunately, i cannot change the way data is store since it's a production database and the impact would be too big.

Share your Model. offset is probably a VARCHAR column and therefore the + arithmetic between TruncDate() and F() is problematic.

So it was a VARCHAR like I said.

Ended up doing a bunch of casting operations:

Create an expression to convert varchar offset to the corresponding hours offset, examples:

+0700 -> (substring) -> +07 -> (cast integer) -> +7
-0200 -> (substring) -> -02 -> (cast integer) -> -2


Inside annotation:

Cast start_time to timestamp to remove timezone
Add offset from expression above to casted start_time


Filter by annotated value
 # extract substring +0700 -> +07 and convert to int +7
 adjusted_offset_expr = ExpressionWrapper(
     Cast(Substr("offset", 1, 3), IntegerField())
     * Cast(timedelta(hours=1), TimeField()),
     output_field=DurationField(),
 )

 # cast start_time to timestamp to remove timezone
 # add offset to start_time
 activity_log = (
     MyModel.objects.annotate(
         adjusted_start_time=ExpressionWrapper(
             Cast("start_time", DateTimeField()) + adjusted_offset_expr,
             output_field=DateTimeField(),
         )
     )
     .filter(
         adjusted_start_time__gte=start_time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC),
     ).values()
 )



